# Symfony cannot load mongodb/driver

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, silex, php-mongodb

I'm trying to implement doctrine ODM. I'm taking baby steps but I keep hitting roadblocks. This is one of the many roadblocks so far:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Manager" from namespace "MongoDB\Driver".
```

When I do this:

```
use MongoDB\Driver\Manager;    
$manager = new Manager("mongodb://10.0.2.2:27017");
$servers = $manager->getServers();
var_dump($servers);
```

I'm requiring

> "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.0",

which in turns require

> "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.0.1"

Is there something I'm missing or that I'm not getting about the whole setup?

Comment: Does the `mongodb` extension show up in `phpinfo()`? And if yes, which version?

Comment: Did you update Symfony  after the changes? Topic: class_map + autoloader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongo was not installed.

To install mongodb

```
pecl install mongodb
```

When you have mongodb installed

```
php -m | grep -i mongo
```

Should output:

```
mongodb
```

Thanks Simon.